# Save simple information for a database within postgress

Tags: postgresql

I have a multi tennant application which will use the SILO Model to save data (each tennant will get an own database).

Because tennant names could be redundand my database are with GUIDs: MyApp_[GUID].

Now I want to save simple but neccesary information for each database like a tennant name and 3 to 5 more informations.

Is there a simple way to write and get these data?

The only way I can think of is to create a special table for this with only 1 row - but it seems a bot of wasting.

Comment: When one database per tenant is not a waste of resources, how could an almost empty table be a waste?

Comment: Because 1 Table is not suited to save 3 simple words...

Comment: Why not? A single column in a record can hold between 0 bytes and 1GB of data. 3 words would fit. You could also create a VIEW to hold the data, but that wouldn't change a lot for the database. And you need a database role with the permissions to create a database object, something I would not advise.

Comment: How do you manage all those databases? It sounds like what you actually want is a separate `MyApp` database with a `databases` table.

Comment: @Bergi We use self written microservices for this :) Manage a SaaS Solution with SILO Model for multi tennants is nothing you can do from today to tomorow, but especially then just "a simple table" is worth thinking into :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simpler solution than a table per database (and having to deal with the awkward constraint that it must have exactly one row), you could

- use a [custom configuration parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html). You can change them with [`ALTER DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html). The downside is that you can only store strings, and that the settings might be overridden per session.
- use a [`COMMENT` on the database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-comment.html). The downside is that you can only store a single string per databasebase; the advantage is that it is automatically shown in many lists of databases such as `psql`'s `\l+` command
- add your own columns to the [`pg_database` system table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/catalog-pg-database.html). You should not mess with that, so it's a spectacularly bad idea even if you knew what you were doing, but in a relational model it's the closest to what you were asking for so I'd mention it for completeness.

I don't really advocate any of these solutions, although they do what you were asking for there's probably a better solution to your actual problem. It might be as simple a table of databases, possibly with a foreign key to `pg_database`, in an extra database shared by all tenants.

Comment: I think the comment it is :) I can easily fit all things I want into a json string and put them there, thank you!